# The tags tell me I'm polluting the main site, but I don't think that's correct (title ver. 3)

Tags: support, tags, scope

So, I want to ask about the name of the Android mascot.  Of course, this has nothing to do with anything but the marketing of the operating system/hardware.

But I can't find any relevant tags.  You all know that the [android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) tag is banned (for probably good reason).  I've tried several alternatives that would apply for my question, e.g., marketing.  But there isn't anything that nearly applies.

I guess this is partly related to the fact that marketing questions are not on topic, but this is (I think) not *that* kind of marketing question.  I want to know a facet of how Google markets Android, not how I can market my Android app.  The help center doesn't differentiate between those kinds.

So I'm coming to you to ask... Is this question off topic?  If not, what tag(s) should/could I use? And to those who answer my original question in the comments, should I bother asking on the main site since you just gave me an answer?

Comment: Oh, child metas, how rarely you are visited :)

Comment: First result of [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=name+of+android+robot) is [this result](http://www.intomobile.com/2009/02/17/so-what-is-the-name-of-the-google-android-robot-anyway/).

Comment: @AlE.: You think I didn't search first?  FYI, if you read that uninformative article, it gives *multiple* names.  None of which is cited as the "official" name.

Comment: Well, guess what? That's about the extent of the public information that's out there about the name of the Android mascot, if it does have a name. Unless someone from Google wanders in to answer your proposed question, it's essentially unanswerable and will simply invite guesses and speculation. So it'll be off-topic that way.

Comment: @AlE.: You're probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your question is on-topic here.

The name of the Android mascot has nothing to do with how Android works. It's not a difficulty you're having with an app, or how to root a specific model of phone, or how to recover a deleted photo.

It's idle curiosity about how Google is marketing the OS.

Would questions about the clydesdales be on-topic for http://beer.stackexchange.com?

How about "why is there a bite out of the apple" at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)?

There may be places where this question would be welcome, but not here.

Comment: I disagree. It's a perfectly reasonable question about Android, asked from an end-user point of view. I know that a lot of the questions we get are support questions, but that doesn't mean other things aren't welcome.

Comment: @DanHulme What about using Android involves the name of the mascot?

Comment: @MatthewRead The part where you see this thing every day and you want to describe it to someone else and you just don't know what to call it. Not everything on the site has to be troubleshooting.